# vlc shows my stream image cropped/offset

Tags: command-line, debian, vlc-media-player, streaming

I'm trying to play a stream from a security camera with a command in **Debian**, but it shows the image cut off and scrolled up.

[image]

```
cvlc -f http://192.168.1.37:9981/stream/mux/b042b193aeaef7671941bed57e8af952?ticket=41ea357448ca1d710f20d4f83ea47e8b34c486f4
```

I don't know how to make it take up the whole screen. I have tried internally in the configuration without success, I have also tried this way, and it does not solve it.

```
cvlc -f --video-x=100 --video-y=100 http://192.168.1.37:9981/stream/mux/b60554771be49d5979c69999351d1e90?ticket=9968b324fdcf6a2ed87566bc88fdcc922dadcc0
```

I don't know what else to try, I can't find a way to fix it. The PC is an **x86 Acer Iconia** tablet and the screen has a resolution of **1280x800**. I want the video to fit the screen without clipping or scrolling. The stream is from a **raspberry pi cam** at **1920x1080**.

I have tried with another stream from my mobile (ip cam) as if it were a security camera and the image also appears displaced, so the problem must be the **vlc**. Can you help me?

Comment: For a quick fix, try a different player that is just as good (even better in my opinion).  [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/en/downloads).  It is probably already included in your package manager.  See if it mirrors the unwanted behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much mate. I will try it. I'm testing mpv now and it seems like a great player. You can do a lot of things that you can't with vlc.